# Combine Multiple string-array Resources

Tags: android

I have multiple different categories and in each category I use one string resource to populate a ListView like so:

```
<string-array name="list">
        <item>item1</item>
        <item>item2</item>
        <item>item3</item>
    </string-array>
```

I call them like so:

```
String[] list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list);
```

How can I combine these into one String[] to use as an "All" list.

Answer (score 1):

you can combine two Array List into a single one Like this:

```
ArrayList<String> first;
ArrayList<String> second;
second.addAll(first);
```

Since you use Simple Array there a multiple way to change arrays to arrayList, you can fetch for it on the net. But why you are not storing them on a single array in xml file that you call it global_content for exemple. You are waisting time and memory for this!!

Comment: How do I do that if I had like 10 of them?

Comment: And also, I am using arrays, Not arrayLists

Comment: there a multiple way to change array to arrayList you can find it on the net. but why you are not storing them on a single array in xml file. for the approach i give it to you: you can use:

array10.addAll(array9.addAll(array8)) but i advice you to store them on a single array that you will call it global_content or something like that